# jQuery add/remove class for multiple elements

Tags: jquery, if-statement, addclass, toggleclass

I have a number of buttons that I'm adding/removing a class on click. My script turns all the buttons off before turning the clicked button on. The problem with this is one button is always set to on when I would like the ability to turn it off when it's clicked a second time.  I've tried using if statements and is(), but nothing's worked yet. Can someone lend me a hand?

```
$('.silver_button').live('click', function () {
  $('.checked').text('Select').removeClass('checked');
  $(this).text("").addClass('checked');

  if ($('.challenge_card .silver_button').is('.checked')) {
    $('.silver_button').text("Select").removeClass("checked");
  }

});
```

Comment: Is `.challenge_card` the identifier for your special case button? Does it also inherit the `.silver_button` class? Do you want your special case button to stay enabled unless it's clicked specifically?

Comment: Its quite hard to understand what you want to do. Perhaps because the meaning in the classes means nothing without the context. You click a button and all the buttons clear their text value except the clicked button? However what happens when you click your challenge_card? The same as the others, or nothing, or only after 2 clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.silver_button').live('click', function () {

    if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {

        $(this).text("Select").removeClass("checked");

    } else {

        $('.checked').text('Select').removeClass('checked');
        $(this).text("").addClass('checked');

    }

});
```